# Action Script. How to disable keyboard?

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript, timer, keyboard, disabled-control

how to disable keyboard keys in Action Script?

I'm creating Flash "memory" game, Idea to discover 2 equal cards. When 2nd card is discovered it is shown for 750 milliseconds, in that time player can't do any actions.
When I use this `mouseChildren = false;` player can't click with mouse for this time, but he can use keyboard arrows/enter/space/tab buttons... I need to disable It for this time.

Here is part of my code:

```
            {
                    trace("Wrong");
                    _message = "Wrong";
                    message_txt.text = _message;
                     _secondCard = event.currentTarget;


                    var timer:Timer = new Timer(750, 1);
                    timer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER_COMPLETE, flipBack);
                    timer.start();

                stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, blindKeyboard);//added here
                stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, blindKeyboard);//added here


                    mouseChildren = false;


                }
            }

function blindKeyboard(e:KeyboardEvent):void{ //added here function
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
}

            protected function flipBack(event:TimerEvent):void
    {
        _firstCard.gotoAndPlay("flipBack");
        _secondCard.gotoAndPlay("flipBack");
        _firstCard.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, checkCards);
        _secondCard.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, checkCards);
        _firstCard = _secondCard = undefined; 
        mouseChildren = true;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just have functions for adding/removing listeners :

```
function addListeners():void
{
    // loop through and add the listeners for the cards
    // add keyboard listeners
}

function removeListeners():void
{
   // loop through and remove listeners from the cards
   // remove keyboard listeners
}
```

Before you set the timer, you remove your listeners :

```
removeListeners();
```

Then in your flipback timer handler you just call the addListeners :

```
addListeners();
```

Comment: same as adding - just use removeEventListener instead of addEventListener

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, blindKeyboard);
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, blindKeyboard);
function blindKeyboard(e:KeyboardEvent):void{
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for answer, but this doesn't help - the same. I can use keyboard all the time.

Comment: Updated. I tried this with a simple TextInput and it worked fine

Comment: Amm... The same. Doesn't work... I updated my question where I placed my code. Maybe i did it incorrect?

Comment: Place the stage.addEventListener-Lines not in a method but simply in the first keyframe

Comment: Hmmm... Can you upload you project somewhere, so I can take a look? Since it´s working fine here :(